# Calling a method that is defined by a public interface?

Tags: java, interface

I'm having some trouble understanding this code. The content variable is an interface. I'm having trouble understanding how it's possible to call the method directly on the interface that isn't implemented by another class. Am I missing some java fundamental? Or does this have to do with the fact that it's autowired?

```
public class Utils {
        
    @Autowired
    private Content cContent;

    @TraceMethod
    public ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> getCMSContent(Locale locale, String businessId, String appId, String contentType, String contentId) {
        
        CMContent content=null;
        try {
            content = cContent.getContent(locale.getValue(), businessId, appId, contentType, contentId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error in content call");
        }
        ...
        ...
}
```

The Interface

```
public interface Content {
    CMContent getContent(String var1, String var2, String var3, String var4, String var5) throws Exception;
 }
```

Comment: what is `Content`? is it something from a library or in-built in your project. If the functionality is in the working state, there has to be an implementation somewhere, depending on the editor you are using you can figure that out

Comment: You show no initialization of cContent, unless that's what @Autowired does for you.  But cContent needs to be assigned a reference to an instance of a class that implements Content.

Comment: Spring framework will find the implementation of `Content` and inject it to `cContent` variable

Answer (score 2):

The code is designed to use a dependency injection framework, e.g. Spring.

When Spring creates an instance of `Utils`, it will find another object in its context which implements `Content`, and assign that to `cContent`. That's the meaning of the `@Autowired` annotation.

Making the type of the field an interface rather than a concrete type allows different implementations of the interface to be used in different circumstances. For instance, a mock can be used for unit testing the `Utils` class, or Spring could be using a factory to create the implementation, and provide a different implementation depending on how the application is configured.